# I need to embed some forms into a new site

Tags: form, embed

We are moving to a new Craft site and we have some forms that live on our form server. I am wanting to embed these forms into the appropriate pages.

There is a PHP file that I can download that looks Like this:

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());
header("p3p: CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""); 
session_start();

require("/var/www/html/machform/machform.php");

$mf_param['form_id'] = 10824;
$mf_param['base_path'] = 'https://myform.mydomain.com/';
$mf_param['show_border'] = true;
display_machform($mf_param);

?>
```

Or I can get embed codes for iFrames, etc...What I don't see is a way to add the embed code into an existing page.  Is there a plugin for that? How do I edit the HTM to embed the form on the page?

Thanks for helping this Craft NooB.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a 'Plain Text' field, named `iframe` and allow it to have multiple lines. You can put your embed code in there.

Then you can add the iframe in your template with `{{ entry.iframe|raw }}`.

For (a little) more info about the raw filter: [Here's the twig docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html)